# How to apply dynamic layouts in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a simple Nuxt 3 project with dynamic pages and some custom layouts:

```
/pages
  /item
    [id].vue
```

```
/layouts
  default.vue
  FooLayout.vue
  BarLayout.vue
  BazLayout.vue
```

I want to apply custom layouts based on a different `item group`, something like this:

#### entities.json

```json
{
  1: 'FooLayout',
  2: 'BarLayout',
  3: 'BazLayout'
}
```

#### dataset.json

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "group": 1,
    ...
  }
]
```

#### [id].vue

```js
<script setup>
import items from '~/assets/static/dataset.json';
import { GROUPS } from '~/assets/entities.json';
const route = useRoute();

const params = route.params;
const ITEM_ID = params.itemId;

const item = items.find((item) => item.id == ITEM_ID);

const LAYOUT_GROUP = GROUPS[item.group];

definePageMeta({
  layout: LAYOUT_GROUP // <-- expected to be: 'FooLayout'
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
   {{ item }}
  </div>
</template>
```

---

But now I see the following error message and don't know how I can apply a custom layout based on the `LAYOUT_GROUP`:

#### Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: LAYOUT_GROUP is not defined

### Approach 2:

if I'm using `<NuxtLayout :name="LAYOUT_GROUP">`

I will see the following warning:

> Invalid layout `FooLayout` selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I see the layout name must be start as lowercase, or be in kebab-case, like the [documentation mentioned](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts#layouts-directory):

> The layout name is normalized to kebab-case

I couldn't implement it with `definePageMeta`. There comes still the not defined error.

But with `:name="'foo'"` it works.